# Exchange 2000 public folders to Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

We've got a bit of a situation where an Exchange 2000 system was migrated to 2010 and all was fine. That was a few months ago and the 2000 server was retired. Some bright sparks just realised the public folders were never transfered across. So I've booted up the 2000 server and I can't access any of the public folder (although the folders are displayed)

[image]

So my question is now, how do I export all the public folders from one server to the 2010 server?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever uninstall Exchange 2000? It can't coexist with Exchange 2010 in the same organization. Once you've uninstalled any supported downlevel Exchange versions from a 2010 organization (2003, 2007), they can't be added back.

If your Exchange 2000 server still has the database files on it, I'd suggest opening a PSS case to see if there's anything Microsoft can do to export the contents of that database to a format you can import into 2010.

Make sure anything you try to do is on a copy of your database files and not the originals.